# How can we make Rust struct instance methods available to Vue frontend using Tauri?

Tags: vue.js, rust, tauri

in short, Tauri application using Rust backend and Vue frontend.
The *#[tauri::command]* is good and all for pure functions, but what happens if we need to preserve some kind of state in the backend, lets say that of a struct instance?
This is my example:

Tauri entry point: main.rs

```
mod random_number_generator;
use random_number_generator::RandomNumberGenerator;

fn main() {
    // instance to manage the vector state
    let ng = RandomNumberGenerator::new();

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![generate]) <-- how to access the "generate" of ng?
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

A simple struct and its implementation: random_number_generator.rs.

```
use rand::Rng;

pub struct RandomNumberGenerator
{
    used_numbers_repository: Vec<i64>,
}

impl RandomNumberGenerator {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        RandomNumberGenerator {
            used_numbers_repository: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    #[tauri::command]  <-- this is not allowed
    pub fn generate(&mut self, minimum: i64, maximum: i64) -> String {
        if minimum < 0 {
            return format!("Random number between {} and {}: minimum must be positive.", minimum, maximum);
        }

        if minimum >= maximum {
            return format!("Random number between {} and {}: maximum must be more than minimum.", minimum, maximum);
        }

        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut number: i64 = rng.gen_range(minimum..maximum + 1);

        while self.used_numbers_repository.contains(&number) {
            number = rng.gen_range(minimum..maximum + 1);
        }

        self.used_numbers_repository.push(number);
        format!("A random number between {} and {}? Here you go: {}.", minimum, maximum, number)
    }

    #[tauri::command]  <-- this is not allowed
    pub fn used_numbers(&self) -> String {
        self.used_numbers_repository.iter().map( |&id| id.to_string() + " ").collect()
    }
}
```

A simple vue component: RandomGenerator.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { invoke } from "@tauri-apps/api/tauri";

const generatedMessage = ref("");
const minimum = ref(0);
const maximum = ref(999);

async function generate() {
    generatedMessage.value = await invoke("generate", { minimum: minimum.value, maximum: maximum.value })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" v-model="minimum" placeholder="minimum" />
    <input type="number" v-model="maximum" placeholder="maximum" />
    <button type="button" @click="generate()">Generate</button>
  </div>

  <p>{{ generatedMessage }}</p>
</template>
```

#[tauri::command] is not allowed to struct methods.

Could that be possible without using some other packages, for state management for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `#[tauri::command]` is good and all for pure functions, but what happens if we need to preserve some kind of state in the backend, lets say that of a struct instance?

In Tauri you'd do this not with methods, but with [`State`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.State.html) handled by your Tauri app with the [`Manager::manage`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/trait.Manager.html#method.manage) method (similar to how endpoints in Rust web frameworks like Actix, Axum or Rocket work). Read more about state management in tauri in [this section](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command#accessing-managed-state) of the guide.

I.e. this could be a setup that works for Tauri using your `RandomNumberGenerator` as state while exposing your `generate` command to Vue.js:

```rust
use tauri::State;

pub struct RandomNumberGenerator
{
    used_numbers_repository: Vec<i64>,
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn generate(rng: State<RandomNumberGenerator>, minimum: i64, maximum: i64) -> String {
    todo!();
}

fn main() {
    let ng = RandomNumberGenerator::new();

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .manage(ng) // manage ng as app state
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![generate])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

In Vue you'd invoke this command like you do in your example:

```js
await invoke("generate", { minimum: minimum.value, maximum: maximum.value })
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that will work as soon as I solve my mut problems in the rust side.

Comment: If you want to mutate your state, you must wrap it in a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), which implements [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Took me some time to implement, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After the accepted answer, the code in *main.rs* became like this:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

use tauri::State;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use number_generator::RandomNumberGenerator;
mod number_generator;

#[tauri::command]
fn generate(rng: State<Mutex<RandomNumberGenerator>>, minimum: i64, maximum: i64) -> String {
    rng.lock().unwrap().generate(minimum, maximum)
}

#[tauri::command]
fn numbers(rng: State<Mutex<RandomNumberGenerator>>) -> String {
    rng.lock().unwrap().used_numbers()
}


fn main() {
    let rng = Mutex::new(RandomNumberGenerator::new());

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .manage(rng)
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![generate, numbers])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

And added in Generate.vue:

```
...
const generatedMessage = ref("");
const usedNumbers = ref("");
...
generatedMessage.value = await invoke("generate", { minimum: minimum.value, maximum: maximum.value })
usedNumbers.value = await invoke("numbers")
...
<h4>Used numbers</h4>
<p>{{ usedNumbers }}</p>
```